# Setting initial value on text input hook

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

If I have to set initial value of name input field to be:

```
const [name, setName] = useState(userProfileDataFetched.name); //This doesn't show anything on input field
```

instead of

```
const [name, setName] = useState('test'); // This works
```

where getRequest is (just for reference sake)

```
const [userProfileDataFetched, setUserProfileDataFetched] = useState('')
```

Also for reference sake:
userProfileDataFetched is set as  `setUserProfileDataFetched(response.data);`

So that the dynamic value getRequest.name is visible on the input text.

and then allow it to change its value on input text

so, have kept the input tag like:

```
 <TextInput style={styles.input} name={Name}
                          value={name}
     onChangeText={value=>console.log(value)}/>
```

How's can we do set initial dynamic value using hook and then allow it to change it. Either the text is not visible or else, its not editable if i write it on  field.

Comment: You need to provide more context. What does getRequest look like? Instead of providing just that snippet, provide a minimal example component that illustrates the issue you are having.

Comment: renamed getRequest to userProfileDataFetched for better understanding

Comment: Looks like you're making a request to fetch the user profile data, therefore you can't initialize state with the response, because the request hasn't fired yet. Just set the value once the request returns the data.

Comment: If i set this value in text input, it works, but then, i need some code onChange (can be another solution, don't know how) so that that value can be updated, unable to update the value if i set it to text field as the state doesn't allow that..

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
<TextInput style={styles.input} name={Name}
                      value={name}
 onChangeText={value=>console.log(value)}/>
```

To

```
<TextInput style={styles.input} name={Name}
                      value={name}
 onChangeText={value=> setName(value)}/>
```

Comment: did that, thanks. but this dint help either to resolve the main issue

Answer (score 0):

You could use useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(userProfileDataFetched.name) {
    setName(userProfileDataFetched.name)
  }
}, [userProfileDataFetched])
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume that TextInput is some custom control you have written with an input element somewhere inside it.  Inside the control don't set the value, set the defaultValue property instead.  When you respond to get requests and what not in the parent control Use effect can update an initial control value as so.

```
export default function TextInput({someValue}:{someValue?:string}){

    return(<input type="text" 
         className="myinputstyles" defaultValue={someValue}/>)
}
```

Using hooks to override the normal operation of the react engine is not the right answer.  The default value updates the control value on render and then steps out of the way, allowing the form to behave the way it was designed to behave.

Parent form:

```
export default function SomeForm() {
    const [someValue, setSomeValue] = useState("hello")


    const onGoodbye = (event : any) =>{
        setSomeValue("goodbye");
    }

    return (<form>
          <TextInput someValue={someValue}/>
          <button type="button" 
             onClick={onGoodbye}>Say Goodbye</button>
          </form>)
}
```

In the example above when you update someValue in the onClick event it causes the entire TextInput control to re-render.  Which re-renders the embedded input with a new default value, and then gets out of the way.